# 80 port still running after stopped the site

Tags: iis, web, iis-6, port-number

In some windows machines, after stopped the IIS site which running in 80 port number, still that port number is in use. This issue randomly reproducing in few machines.
Is there a way to stop this port number using C#?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between stopping a website and releasing a port.

IIS could have several sites listening to port 80, all with different host headers.
Stopping a site just means that request's aren't being handled. Try stopping the application pool.

But the ports are in use by the kernel (HTTP.sys) so no guarantee about releasing them.